# Run multiple Python scripts in Azure (using Docker?)

Tags: python, azure, docker, queue

I have a Python script that consumes an Azure queue, and I would like to scale this easily inside Azure infrastructure. I'm looking for the easiest solution possible to

- run the Python script in an environment that is as managed as possible
- have a centralized way to see the scripts running and their output, and easily scale the amount of scripts running through a GUI or something very easy to use

I'm looking at Docker at the moment, but this seems very complicated for the extremely simple task I'm trying to achieve. What possible approaches are known to do this? An added bonus would be if I could scale wrt the amount of items on the queue, but it is fine if we'd just be able to manually control the amount of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/), which also support Python.
This would be a managed and scaleable environment and also supports [background tasks (WebJobs)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) with a central logging.

Azure Web Apps also offer a free plan for development and testing.

Comment: Hey Sascha, Web Apps aren't our way to go, since to scale (add 1 new script instance), we'd be launching a whole new vm, which is not what we want. Additionally, webjobs are only an added bonus to a web-first solution that is intended for Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think CoreOS on Azure can satisfy your needs. You can try to refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-coreos-how-to/ to know how to get started.

CoreOS is a Linux distribution for running Docker as Linux container, that you can remote access via SSH client like `putty`. For using Docker, you can search the key words `Docker tutorial` via Bing to rapidly learning some simple usage that enough for running Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are describing something like a micro-services architecture. From that perspective, Docker is a great choice. I recommend you consider using an orchestration framework such as [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) or [Docker Swarm](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-swarm) which will allow you to run your containers on a cluster of VMs with the ability to easily scale, deploy new versions, rollback and implement load balancing. The schedulers Mesos supports (Marathon and Chronos) also have a [Web UI](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/marathon-ui.html). I believe you can also implement some kind of triggered scaling like you describe but that will probably not be off the shelf.

This does seem like a bit of a learning curve but I think is worth it especially once you start considering the complexities of deploying new versions (with possible rollbacks), monitoring failures and even integrating things like Jenkins and continuous delivery.

For Azure, an easy way to deploy and configure a Mesos or Swarm cluster is by using [Azure Container Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/) (ACS) which does all the hard work of configuring the cluster for you. Find additional info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-intro/